# Tablespace bigfile or not from sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

From sqlplus I'm trying to find if a schema was created using a bigfile tablespace. I was hoping this was stored in the dba_segments or dba_data_files but I couldn't find it either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

schemas and tablespaces are different. A schema can store objects in many tablespaces (permissions allowing).

if you want to see if a given TS is bigfile, then use:

```
SELECT tablespace_name, bigfile FROM dba_tablespaces;
```